# Can I change the solution to the DSU painting subarrays question?

Tags: c++, algorithm, disjoint-sets, union-find

The link to the post about this algorithm which I have a question for is here: https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/disjoint_set_union.html

My question is specifically about this section

> We have a segment of length  $L$ , each element initially has the color 0. We have to repaint the subarray  $[l, r]$  with the color  $c$  for each query  $(l, r, c)$ . At the end we want to find the final color of each cell. We assume that we know all the queries in advance, i.e. the task is offline.

The solution is

```
void make_set(int v) {
    parent[v] = v;
}

int find_set(int v) {
    if (v == parent[v])
        return v;
    return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);
}

for (int i = 0; i <= L; i++) {
    make_set(i);
}

for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int l = query[i].l;
    int r = query[i].r;
    int c = query[i].c;
    for (int v = find_set(l); v <= r; v = find_set(v)) {
        answer[v] = c;
        parent[v] = v + 1;
    }
}
```

My confusion lies in `parent[v] = v + 1`. How I thought about this question is that we should instead do `parent[v] = parent[v] + 1`. Since we can assume that everything between v and parent[v] are already painted.

From my testing, it seems that this change doesn't change the answer but I'm not sure if I might be missing some edge cases.

Would it be correct for me to write `parent[v] = parent[v] + 1` and are there any implications for the time complexity if I were to make this change?

Comment: Oops sorry! I added the function definitions into the code snippet. The `parent` just refers to the parent of the element in the DSU.